# rSync to remote location for mirroring of a plex library. Continual disconnects

Tags: linux, rsync, synology

Attempting to mirror a Plex library to remote.  The following disconnects multiple times per day. Files that are incomplete on disconnect do not resume (I would like them to.)

Suggestions on how to make this more reliable, resume via checksum, and stop disconnecting?

**rsync -avi -b --backup-dir=/volume1/PLEX/removed --progress --append -e 'ssh -p222' /mnt/MoviesMnt user@XX.XX.XX.XX:/volume1/PLEX --delete-after --out-format="%t %f"**

Comment: User --partial
 partial: keep partially transferred files
Using the  --partial
       option tells rsync to keep the partial file which should make a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `--partial` option. It will tell rsync to keep partial files. At the next restart it will reuse this partial file.
Another suggestion may be to use a while loop as:

```
    while true
    do rsync -avi --partial -b --backup-dir=/volume1/PLEX/removed --progress --append -e 'ssh -p222' /mnt/MoviesMnt user@XX.XX.XX.XX:/volume1/PLEX --delete-after --out-format="%t %f" 
    done
```

so if the command will fail it will be automatically  re-executed. You can place it inside of a script, or directly in cli.